# Changing port for phpmyadmin

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, virtualhost

I've got on my VPS tomcat running on the port 80. Nevertheless I want to have there phpmyadmin (running on some other port) as well... I tried to edit `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` , but without any reason - even a default apache website won't appera. On the port 80 works everyhing fine (when tomcat is down).

ports.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:81
Listen 81
```

000-default:

```
<Virtualhost *:81>
```

any idea, how to fix it and have phpmyadmin on other port than just 80?

Comment: To start check if it is listening on 81 with something like `netstat --listen --program --numeric | grep ":81 "` then look at any firewall rules to make sure traffic headed for that port isn't being dropped.

Comment: apache2 seems to be listening on that port `tcp6       0      0 :::81                   :::*                    LISTEN      4174/apache2 
` I don't think that there could be any problem with firewall..or at least I didn't set anything up on that VPS...

Comment: any logs/error_log entries? what does `curl -v -D- localhost:81` say?

Comment: Error log says noting. `curl` gets connected and returns index.html nevertheless 185.8.236.224:81 via web browser displays nothing and times out. Eventhough it works via `curl`..